# Add an Image in a table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

The main idea is being able to controll, upload and delete a slideshow's images from a database.

So, first I connect to the database like this, and with a `while` function I echo all the images I have stored in my db.

This is the code to do that:

```
<?php
$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "SELECT id, img FROM mytable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<img src=".$row['img'].">";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

In the table "mytable" I have 2 columns: an ID auto-inc and a column called img.
How can I store an image in the img column so that my function will echo all the images I have in my table?
All I found searching til now was a lot of methods that upload the image with an html form, but I'd prefer to upload my img directly on my database, without building an html+php form to upload all my images to my table.

Is that possible?

Comment: You just want to store the reference to the image or the actual file data to the column?

Comment: You just opened my eyes. I feel like an idiot now. I don't need the actual image, right? I can just write the image path in the img column and it will work, won't it?

Comment: You could store it, but that's generally not the greatest idea. So, yes! Store the image path!

Comment: Also, you really only want to store the image path if you are doing something special with the rest of the data, like storing the image attributes or something. Or, if you need to reference different images stored in different directories. Generally you can use `scandir()` if all your images are in one folder. All depends on your intended use.

Comment: You can (must) store in database only image's path. But, if you want to be able to upload images, you still will need build html form and PHP script to handle uploading process.

Comment: Best way to store image path in database and images in one folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing entire images in a database is generally a bad idea. It is much simpler to simply store the path of the image inside your database, as has already been mentioned. You may have a bit of extra work deleting the images, as you would need a php system call to delete the image file.
If you really must store images inside a database, you can save them as base64 encoded text. I've seen this be done at a fairly successful company, but no particularly good reason was given for this. Your sql execution time will be substantially larger, because images are large files, and your table size will balloon.